FreeGLUT undefined references
I have tried to get FreeGLUT and been successful before, but now I get undefined reference errors when running any FreeGLUT apps
entire log:
g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -o bin\Debug\fast.exe obj\Debug\main.o   -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libfreeglut.a" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libfreeglut_static.a"
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o: in function `pre_c_init':
C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:115:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `__p__commode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__mingw_app_type[.refptr.__mingw_app_type]+0x0): undefined reference to `__mingw_app_type'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__mingw_initltssuo_force[.refptr.__mingw_initltssuo_force]+0x0): undefined reference to `__mingw_initltssuo_force'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__mingw_initltsdyn_force[.refptr.__mingw_initltsdyn_force]+0x0): undefined reference to `__mingw_initltsdyn_force'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__mingw_initltsdrot_force[.refptr.__mingw_initltsdrot_force]+0x0): undefined reference to `__mingw_initltsdrot_force'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

I'm also using Code::Blocks if that helps at all

I have tried multiple different methods online and so far the one I'm on is the best I can get to, I got this by following this tutorial on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMsTI_CC-jc

You're not mixing 32 and 64 bit code and libraries? How did you install FreeGLUT?

no im not mixing 32 and 64 im using the 32 bit version of freeglut and downloaded it through https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/
and am using the freeglut 3.0.0 MinGW Package
i dowloaded extracted put the include files in C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\GL
the libs in C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\libs
and the dll in C:\Windows

What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?

going to sleep so wont be answering anything for a bit :^)

The x86_64-w64-mingw32 bit indicates that you have a 64-bit installation (even if it have 32 in the name). The default for a 64-bit compiler is to build code in 64-bit mode. So if you installed a 32-bit library then you can't use that. Please [edit] your question to tell us exactly how you installed the library, and from where. Also please tell us the exact commands and arguments you use to build your program.

Your undefined references don't appear to be anything to do with freeglut. So it seems you have multiple issues.

ok thx for that info @john im not quite sure what im doing wrong it may be the fact that ive installed and uninstalled opengl and glfw and glut so many times my computer just doesnt know what to do

@harry Unfortunately I don't have much idea what the problem is. I do notice that beginners often try uninstallation as a solution to a problem they don't understand. It rarely helps, unreported errors during installation are very very rare, but uninstallations that don't work fully (i.e. they don't take you back to the exact same state before the installation) are more common. So, if you can, try and understand the problem before taking any action. If you can, my advice now would be to nuke everything and start again.

@harry Also very important is to use a package manager to do your installations. You have MinGW so you should be handling everything (including your compiler) using MSYS2 and it's package manager pacman

You need to recompile the freeglut Library. Those pre-built binaries are very old that aren't compatible with the newest gcc compiler.

i found out that the problem was i was building in x64 for a x32 lib so i just changed my config to x32 build and it works now

i found out that the problem was i was building in x64 for a x32 lib so i just changed my config to x32 build and it works now
thanks to everyone who tried to help me.
it was just a rookie mistake
